# how to set up a multiple apache virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have installed the Zend framework. However, when I try to set up the virtual host - apache.
localhost doesn't work.its execute zend folder.its out side of wamp folder.

What have I done:

```
    <IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
NameVirtualHost localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/websites/zendy/public"
   ServerName zendy

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:/websites/zendy/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
   ServerName localhost

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

how to work this two virtual hosts?

Comment: have you updated your hosts file with the virtual hosts? `127.0.0.1  localhost 127.0.0.1  zendy.localhost`

Comment: yes.but its not working.its works as before.